# Strange behavior of compose and ObservableTransformer in RxJava when the passed generic extends something

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

While trying to play with compose in RxJava2 I found something I can't really explain.

Suppose we have the following two static methods:

```
object RxUtils {

fun <T> handleResponse(): ObservableTransformer<T, T> {
    return ObservableTransformer { observable ->
        observable.flatMap { t ->
                ObservableFromCallable.fromCallable(object: Callable<T>{
                    override fun call(): T {
                        return t
                    }
            })
        }
    }
}


fun <T: GenericResponse> handleResponse2(): ObservableTransformer<T, T> {
    return ObservableTransformer { observable ->
        observable.flatMap { t ->
            ObservableFromCallable.fromCallable(object: Callable<T>{
                override fun call(): T {
                    return t
                }
            })
        }
    }
}}
```

handleResponse and handleResponse2 are the same, the difference is that in handleResponse2 T extends GenericResponse.

The problem is that when i use handleResponse2 in compose, the object which comes from compose is not an Observable and I can't use any Observable operators.

Example:

```
fun <T: GenericResponse> loadApi2(observable: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
    return observable
            .compose(RxUtils.handleResponse2()) // here is blocked, can't use any other operator
}

fun <T: GenericResponse> loadApi(observable: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
    return observable
            .compose(RxUtils.handleResponse()) //works fine, I can use other operators such as compose, subscribeOn etc

}
```

Comment: I tried same with java and there is no type inference issue. Seems like its kotlin issue. Anyway, you can explicitly specify the type i.e`val hr: ObservableTransformer<T, T> = RxUtils.handleResponse2()`

Comment: Interesting. Thanks! I will look into it.